# Current (2020) money exchange in Lebanon for tourists

Tags: lebanon

The official exchange rate is at 1 USD:1500 Lebanon Pound, however it seems the current street rate is at 1:6000 due to the recent situations (protest, covid, explosion, etc...). I have a trip booked for November 2020 and wonder how should I exchange money to not overpay?

I don't want to put myself in any danger, but don't want to lose out on 4x the value.

Comment: Umm...My crystal ball is a bit cloudy today...

Comment: Very carefully? Is it legal to exchange on the streets and are you trained in not getting scammed, as not all street exchangers are honest.

Comment: Opinion-based, as your risk tolerance and experience will differ from others'.

Comment: When I was in Lebanon last year I used mostly dollars to pay for purchases, restaurants etc... At that time it was indeed 1500 Livres to the Dollar. I don't know what exchange rate the shops would use now, but if the street rate is 1:6000 everything above that would be a win for the store. So just use dollars.